# KafkaConsumer poll method takes unusually long in low-traffic components, causing "Offset commit cannot be completed" error

Tags: java, apache-kafka, microservices

I'm working with a Kafka consumer in one of my microservices and am encountering an error:

> Offset commit cannot be completed since the consumer is not part of an active group for auto partition assignment; it is likely that the consumer was kicked out of the group.

Upon investigation, I introduced a metric named 'interval between poll' to measure the interval between two consecutive `KafkaConsumer#poll` calls. For a problematic microsevices, this interval averages around 30-40 seconds. This is unexpected as my service is designed to poll the consumer every 100ms.

```
while (true) {
    ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(100));
    // Process records...
    Thread.sleep(100);
}
```

To dig deeper, I added more metrics to pinpoint where the delay occurs. My findings indicate that almost the entirety of this interval is taken up by the `KafkaConsumer#poll` method itself

Interestingly, this problem is evident in only 2 of my microservices. Both these microservices receive infrequent traffic - approximately 1 small message (less than 1KiB) every 5 minutes. Other microservices in my system, which handle much more intensive traffic and larger messages (around 1MiB), do not exhibit this behavior.

```
heartbeat.interval.ms=10000
session.timeout.ms=30000
max.poll.records=100
max.poll.interval.ms=300000
```

Why does the KafkaConsumer#poll method take such a long time in components with low traffic and small message?

here is graph that shows times spent by `KafkaConsumer#poll` in sec
[image: KafkaConsumer#poll duration in sec]

logs

consumer

```
agent.MyAgent  | 11/10/2023 09:45:27.267 ERROR [MessageService on MyAgent-b834fc68614a] ConsumerCoordinator - [Consumer instanceId=MyAgent_b834fc68614a, clientId=consumer-MyAgent-MyAgent_b834fc68614a, groupId=MyAgent] Offset commit failed on partition DiscoveryRequest.Target-2 at offset 265: The coordinator is not aware of this member.

agent.MyAgent  | 11/10/2023 09:45:27.284 ERROR [MessageService on MyAgent-b834fc68614a] ConsumerCoordinator - [Consumer instanceId=MyAgent_b834fc68614a, clientId=consumer-MyAgent-MyAgent_b834fc68614a, groupId=MyAgent] Asynchronous auto-commit of offsets failed: Offset commit cannot be completed since the consumer is not part of an active group for auto partition assignment; it is likely that the consumer was kicked out of the group.. Will continue to join group.

agent.MyAgent  | 11/10/2023 09:45:27.860 WARN  [MessageService on MyAgent-b834fc68614a] ConsumerCoordinator - [Consumer instanceId=MyAgent_b834fc68614a, clientId=consumer-MyAgent-MyAgent_b834fc68614a, groupId=MyAgent] Asynchronous auto-commit of offsets {...} failed: Offset commit cannot be completed since the consumer is not part of an active group for auto partition assignment; it is likely that the consumer was kicked out of the group.
```

kafka logs

```
kafka  | [2023-10-11 09:44:34,120] INFO [GroupCoordinator 1]: Member MyAgent_b834fc68614a-9891de54-09fa-42b0-9df3-7237953297c2 in group MyAgent has failed, removing it from the group (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
kafka  | [2023-10-11 09:44:34,120] INFO [GroupCoordinator 1]: Preparing to rebalance group MyAgent in state PreparingRebalance with old generation 203 (__consumer_offsets-28) (reason: removing member MyAgent_b834fc68614a-9891de54-09fa-42b0-9df3-7237953297c2 on heartbeat expiration) (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
kafka  | [2023-10-11 09:44:34,120] INFO [GroupCoordinator 1]: Group MyAgent with generation 204 is now empty (__consumer_offsets-28) (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
kafka  | [2023-10-11 09:45:27,571] INFO [GroupCoordinator 1]: Static member with groupInstanceId=MyAgent_b834fc68614a and unknown member id joins group MyAgent in Empty state. Created a new member id MyAgent_b834fc68614a-80adc162-5dae-4769-8eea-cd2fd0ac5ad2 for this member and add to the group. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
kafka  | [2023-10-11 09:45:27,571] INFO [GroupCoordinator 1]: Preparing to rebalance group MyAgent in state PreparingRebalance with old generation 204 (__consumer_offsets-28) (reason: Adding new member MyAgent_b834fc68614a-80adc162-5dae-4769-8eea-cd2fd0ac5ad2 with group instance id Some(MyAgent_b834fc68614a); client reason: encountered UNKNOWN_MEMBER_ID from OFFSET_COMMIT response) (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
```

Comment: If your consumer has debug logs, could you please add them. Basically want logs of this timeline -> consumer consumes some message, consumer is idle, consumer gets some message again. Following these logs could help determine what happens to the consumer.

Comment: if everthing else is fine as you say and the poll() is the one to blame than you might wanna check if you are sending heartbeats regularly, and that your consumers are not spending too much in rebalancing/partition assignment...

Comment: @abhinav-ghosh im not sending heartbeats manually, as I know it should be sent with every poll automatically, and Im using static membership - so no rebalancing